# Using The REST API How To Pull All Custom Posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, rest-api

What I am trying to do is pull back all posts of a custom post type. I know with the WordPress REST API you can add per_page=100 to the end of the REST API to pull back 100 posts, but I need a way to pull back ALL of the posts from a custom post type.

After doing some research I found this function:

```
function rest_posts_per_page( $args, $request ) {
    $max = max( (int)$request->get_param( 'per_page' ), 1000 );
    $args['posts_per_page'] = $max;
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'rest_post_query', 'rest_posts_per_page', 10, 2 );
```

Which switches the amount of posts pulled back from the REST API to 1000 by default.

This works great for the default post, but I need this to work with custom post types as well, since the above function only appears to work with the default post. So what I am trying to figure out is how what is needed for the above function to work with a custom post type instead of the default post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter is `dynamic`, i.e. generated from `rest_{$post_type}_query`.

So for the `post` post type it's `rest_post_query` and for the `cpt` post type it's `rest_cpt_query`

Note that REST pagination is available:

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=100&page=1
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=100&page=2
...
```

The maximum of `per_page` is to reduce the risk of fatal errors if available resources are exceeded when too many items are fetched.